# Unable to install any packages to PyCharm and given error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I recently installed PyCharm on my computer. I am trying to install packages for python writing into PyCharm, but I am unable to install any. They all give the same error: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plotly". Plotly is simply an example here. I have inserted an image of the error as well. Any help that can be given is appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: you can simply install the packages using the terminal tab in pycharm

Answer (score 1):

Open up the terminal tab in the bottom left corner, the use pip install to install a package.
If you are still having trouble make sure python is in your environmental variables, to do this goto control panel then programs and features, find python select it then hit change and then modify, make sure "pip" is ticked then hit next, make sure "add python to environment variables" is ticked, then hit install. Once that has finished try to install a package again.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I get the same error message. I tried both installing from the terminal and added python to environment variables.

Comment: Are you able to install from the windows command line rather than through pycharm?

Comment: No. It looked like it would install successfully then hung indefinitely. At this point I may uninstall and reinstall everything.

Comment: Before you do that it might be worth running the repair build in pythons installer incase its an issue with python

Comment: I uninstalled python and pycharm and then reinstalled both. Problem finally fixed. Appreciate the assistance!